# Solving limit without L'Hôpital (without square root)

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

Without using L'Hopital's rule, evaluate $\lim_{x\to6} \frac{x^3−3x^2-x-102}{x-6}$. Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $x^3-3x^2-x-102=(x-6)(x^2+3x+17)$

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Do you mean  $x^3-3x^2-x-102$ in the nuymerator?

Comment: Hi Bernard, yes, that's the numerator and x-6 is the denominator. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By factorizing $x^3-3x^2-x-102$, we get $$x^3-3x^2-x-102=(x-6)(x^2+3x+17)$$
Therefore, the limit becomes:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 6}\dfrac{x^3-3x^2-x-102}{x-6}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 6}\dfrac{(x-6)(x^2+3x+17)}{x-6}\\=\lim_{x\rightarrow 6} (x^2+3x+17)=6^2+3(6)+17=\boxed{71}$$

Comment: You're allowed to cancel out the $(x-6)$'s like that?

Comment: Yes, by understanding $p/p=1$.

Comment: Except it's $\lim\limits_{x\to 6}$.

Comment: @guest: When computing such a limit, one only takes values $x \neq 6$ into account, so it's safe to cancel  $(x-6)$.